# Move to another subscription: Cannot move resources because some site(s) are hosted by other resource group(s) but located in resource group 'XXX'

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I have resource group "MyResources", that contains 4 resources:

- AppService - `myserver`,
- AppServicePlan - `MyServerWestEuFarm`,
- ApplicationInsights - `myserver-insights`,
- StoregeAccount - `myserverstorage`

When I try to move them to another subscription, I get error message:

> Cannot move resources because some site(s) are hosted by other resource group(s) but located in resource group 'MyResources'. The list of sites and corresponding hosting resource groups: myserver:vyvojari.sk'. This may be a result of prior move operations. Move the site(s) back to respective hosting resource groups and try again. (Code: BadRequest, Target: Microsoft.Web/serverFarms)

What does that mean? Especially `myserver:vyvojari.sk` is confusing.

`"vyvojari.sk"` is another resource group and it may be possible that I've created `myserver` appservice in that resource group in the past and moved. So what?

In the resource explorer for the myserver AppService I see:

```
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-d9e0-4769-8440-8cd7968bf94d/resourceGroups/MyResources/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myserver",
  "name": "myserver",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "kind": "app",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "properties": {
    "name": "myserver",
    "state": "Running",
    "hostNames": [
      "myserver.azurewebsites.net"
    ],
    "webSpace": "vyvojari.sk-WestEuropewebspace",
    "selfLink": "https://waws-prod-am2-071.api.azurewebsites.windows.net/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-d9e0-4769-8440-8cd7968bf94d/webspaces/vyvojari.sk-WestEuropewebspace/site/myserver",
    "repositorySiteName": "myserver",
```

But what is webspace and selflink? How can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be too obvious but I think, they want you to move back the 'myserver' resource to the 'vyvojari.sk' resource group. Once that is done, do the subscription operation.

It is possible that although, myserver is in the current resource (you have said that you may have moved it here) is still 'hosted' in that vyvojari resource group despite being part of the current group. By this logic, looks like moving it back to vyvojari should allow you do your subscription related task.

Comment: Ok, but if the app service remained in vyvojari.sk webspace when I moved it to "MyResources", the same will happen again when I try to move it to new resource group in another subscription

Comment: I was thinking that you could try one thing at a time. Take care of subscription movement, then, move groups. Worst comes to worst, you could always contact Azure support. This being an 'administrative' issue, I think they will do this for free.

Comment: I've deleted and recreated the resource, so no support is needed, but I thought it may be useful for others. Unfortunatelly I cannot try to move it back to the original resource group, since I deleted it already.

Comment: delete and recreate...yeah, sometimes that is the only way. You should put that step as an answer, since that is what eventually fixed it.

Comment: In our case, the original resource group has already been deleted. We want to avoid recreating the resource in the new subscription, because the resource is large and constantly accessed. Any other ideas for working around this?

Comment: if you look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

here is the excerpt - "if you move a SQL Server and its database to a new resource group, an application that uses the database experiences no downtime. It can still read and write to the database"

So, when you move, you should still be okay.

Answer (score 0):

You should have moved the resources back to original resource group (as per the error, myResources), migrate to different subscription, and than re-segment them into respected resource groups, as needed.